# Computational difficulty of simulating charge distributions on highly asymmetric surface?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, computational-physics, simulations

I am wondering if anyone happens to know the computational methods - and hence the computational complexity - of simulating the distribution of an electric charge (how electrons distribute) over a surface.  In particular, I am curious about the computational difficulty in simulating the distribution of electrons over a highly asymmetric and non-uniform surface (like the surface of a rough rock).  How does the simulation complexity scale with the complexity of the surface and the precision/accuracy of measurement?

Comment: We do not even know the exact distribution of charge on the surface of perfect parallel plate disc capacitors, even though that is quite easy to simulate. If you have sharp points, the difficulty will spike as well. Do you need a quantitative estimate or something?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent either a rough asymptotic estimate or a quantitative estimate would be nice.  Namely, if one can measure the charge on say some small portion of a highly complex surface with some accuracy, how much compute would be needed to get the same result?